# Subset data frame column using pipe and dot

Tags: r, dataframe, pipe, subset, magrittr

I want to learn how to properly use the "." when subsetting with magrittr.

Given a dataframe `myDataframe`,

```
myDataFrame <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,3,3,4,5), c(10,11,12,13,14,15,16))
#  c.1..2..3..3..3..4..5. c.10..11..12..13..14..15..16.
#1                      1                            10
#2                      2                            11
#3                      3                            12
#4                      3                            13
#5                      3                            14
#6                      4                            15
#7                      5                            16
```

I want to remove all rows with 3 in the first column, which I could do with `myDataFrame[ myDataFrame[,1] != 3 ,]` to get this result:

```
#  c.1..2..3..3..3..4..5. c.10..11..12..13..14..15..16.
#1                      1                            10
#2                      2                            11
#6                      4                            15
#7                      5                            16
```

However, I need to do it with a pipe (and I can't name the columns of the dataframe).

When I try to run `myDataFrame %>% "[" (.[,1] != 3)` I get an "undefined columns selected" error. How do I select one column within a dataframe referred to with a dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can keep it in a `{}` i.e.

```
myDataFrame %>% 
       {.[.[[1]] != 3,]}
#    c.1..2..3..3..3..4..5. c.10..11..12..13..14..15..16.
#1                      1                            10
#2                      2                            11
#6                      4                            15
#7                      5                            16
```

Or in an extended form

```
myDataFrame %>% 
          {`[`(.[,1]) != 3} %>%
                        myDataFrame[.,]
```

Comment: Thank you, really helpful. Is there any reason to use `{.[(.[[1]] != 3),]}` rather than `{.[(.[,1] != 3),]}`? I know dataframes are technically lists, but it seems to me more intuitive and readable to treat it like a matrix.

Comment: @wtrs  It is only because that will work for both `data.frame` and `tibble`/data.table etc.

Answer (score 2):

dplyr method:

```
myDataFrame %>% 
  filter_at(vars(1), any_vars(. != 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you give only one argument to `[.data.frame`, it will be used to subset columns.

You can add only one character and make your form work:

```
myDataFrame %>% "[" (.[,1] != 3,)
```